# Missing number in array in C programming

Tags: c, arrays, missing-data

Given an array C of size N-1 and given that there are numbers from 1 to N with one element missing, the missing number is to be found.

Input:
The first line of input contains an integer T denoting the number of test cases. For each test case first line contains N(size of array). The subsequent line contains N-1 array elements.

Output:
Print the missing number in array.

This problem is to find the missing number in a series of n integers. but, while using the below code I could not get the output as expected.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    //code
    int T,run,i;
    scanf("%d", &T);
    long N,res,C,en;
    long arra[1];
    for (run = 0;run <T; run++ )
    { 
        long arra[T];
        scanf("%ld", &N);
        res =0;
        for (i = 0; i <N-1; i++)
        {
            scanf("%ld",&C);
            res = res + C;
        }
        en = ((N*(N+1))/2)- res; // subtracting the overall sum of array elements from N integers 
        arra[run]=en; //saving it to array
    }
    for(run = 0; run < T; run++)
    {
        printf("%ld ",arra[run]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I expected the below input and output:

```
Input:
2
5
1 2 3 5
10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 10

Output:
4
9
```

but actual output is

```
1 -8719623343620674816
```

Answer (score 2):

You re-declared the variable `arra` inside the `for` loop. So when you assign to `arra[run]`, you're assigning to the inner array, not the one in the `main()` function. So you get garbage when you try to print the contents of the array at the end.

You also declared the first array with only one element, rather than `T` elements.

Get rid of the second declaration, and change the first one from

```
long arra[1];
```

to

```
long arra[T];
```

Answer (score 0):

## correct code

declare the arra before the for loop else for every iteration the arra will be re declared deleting the previous values in it

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    //code
    int T,run,i;
    scanf("%d", &T);
    long N,res,C,en;
    long arra[T];
    for (run = 0;run <T; run++ )
    { 
        scanf("%ld", &N);
        res =0;
        for (i = 0; i <N-1; i++)
        {
            scanf("%ld",&C);
            res = res + C;
        }
        en = ((N*(N+1))/2)- res; // subtracting the overall sum of array elements from N integers 
        arra[run]=en; //saving it to array
    }
    for(run = 0; run < T; run++)
    {
        printf("%ld ",arra[run]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a self explainable simple example

```
  public static void Main()
{
    int[] ary = { 5, 11, 3, 7, 13, 15 }; //{ 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 15 };
    Array.Sort(ary);
    int freq=0;
    int minval = ary[0];
    int[] correct = new int[ary.Length+1];

    int[,] freqs = new int[(ary.Length), 2];
    freqs[0, 0] = 1;
    freqs[0, 1] = ary[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < ary.Length-1; i++)
    {
        int dif = ary[i + 1] - ary[i];
        int res = Search(freqs, dif);
        if (res < 0)
        {
            freqs[i, 0] = 1;
            freqs[i, 1] = dif;
        }
        else
        {
            freqs[res, 0] = freqs[res, 0] + 1;

        }            
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < freqs.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
      
        freq =freqs[i, 0] >freq? freqs[i, 1] : freq;

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < correct.Length;i++)
    {
        correct[i] = i == 0 ? minval :( correct[i - 1] + freq);
    }

    foreach (int i in correct.Except(ary))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("eksik değer="+i);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();



    int Search(int[,] matrix, int val)
    {
        int hit = -99;
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            if (val == matrix[i, 1])
                return i;
        }
        return hit;
    }
}
```